# Error trying to run app with Tesseract OCR Phonegap Plugin for android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ocr, tesseract

I have followed the instructions found here: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/05/15/create-an-ocr-android-app-with-cordova-and-tesseract to create an app that uses the tesseract OCR  phonegap plugin for android, but I am getting the following errors:

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } plugins/com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin/www/tesseractPlugin.js:10
Uncaught Error: Module com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin.TesseractPlugin does not exist. cordova.js:1418
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1183
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova.js:1176
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova.js:1176
Uncaught ReferenceError: Camera is not defined index.html:62'
```

I'm not sure why. 
I think the plugin is in the right place. I have tried removing the curly braces, but they seem to get re-added during the cordova build process.